# How to play audio while i am on the call, which can be listened by the other person called me....?

Tags: android, call, media

I am having a requirement such that, when i am on call.

I want to play a audio to that can be listened by other person who is on the call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accept it or not but simple and reliable answer is you can't. I have wasted my 3 days over it :P

Comment: How do google call screen, plays audio to the incoming call?